# SharedPreferences on a null object reference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to implement a functionality i.e. if the network connection is on then  app will hit the api. I have added network connectivity code in parent activity and calling a method from its fragment but I am getting null object reference error. I am adding code. Please check.

**Parent Activity Code to Call Function From Fragment:**

```
 private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    String message;
    int color;
    if (isConnected) {


        **FinalizePreOrderFragment finalizePreOrderFragment = new FinalizePreOrderFragment(this);
        finalizePreOrderFragment.finalizePreOrderApi();**


    }
```

**Code for Fragment to Call Api**

```
public void finalizePreOrderApi() {

    // pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = Constants.Pre_Order;

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    final SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    HashMap<String, String> loggedDetails = sessionManager.getLoggedUserDetails();

    params.put("api_token", loggedDetails.get("api_token"));
    params.put("user_id", loggedDetails.get("id"));
    params.put("shops_order_list", lis);

    Log.e("TAG", "preOrderApi: " + params);


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.e("pre_order_response", response.toString());
                    try {
                        if (response.has("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Activity activity = getActivity();
                        if (activity != null && isAdded()) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.some_error_occured, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    //       pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (activity != null && isAdded()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.some_error_occured, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
}
```

I am using **SharedPreference**  at below point :

```
final SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        HashMap<String, String> loggedDetails = sessionManager.getLoggedUserDetails();
```

I am saving my preferences in session manager class. And getting error at below point:

```
 public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
```

[image: Error in session manager]

Comment: Where are you storing sharedPrefrences?

Comment: Show SessionManager  class. Are you getting exception in fragment in or in SessionManager  class?

Comment: public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
} .   This code is in my session manager class where I am getting error @Piyush

Comment: `getActivity()` is returning null at `new SessionManager(getActivity())` because `finalizePreOrderFragment` isn't attached to the `Activity`. Why are you creating a new `FinalizePreOrderFragment` instance just to call the `finalizePreOrderApi()` method? Are you sure that method needs to be in a `Fragment` at all?

Comment: Yes, I am sure method needs to be in Fragment @MikeM.

Comment: Then you can't call `finalizePreOrderApi()` until it's attached to the `Activity`; i.e., basically until after its `FragmentTransaction` has completed.

Comment: If you have already fragment instance in activity then you don't need to re-create it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your `getLoggedUserDetails()` method.

```java
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFRENCE_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE); 
//Lets say you have stored user_id in object retrieve it 
int mUserId = prefs.getInt("user_id", 0);//default is 0
if (mUserId >0)
 //Return your Object
else
 //User is not logged in or stored in Prefrences
```